# Top N items from a Spark DataFrame/RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, top-n

My requirement is to get the top N items from a dataframe.

I've this DataFrame:

```
val df = List(
      ("MA", "USA"),
      ("MA", "USA"),
      ("OH", "USA"),
      ("OH", "USA"),
      ("OH", "USA"),
      ("OH", "USA"),
      ("NY", "USA"),
      ("NY", "USA"),
      ("NY", "USA"),
      ("NY", "USA"),
      ("NY", "USA"),
      ("NY", "USA"),
      ("CT", "USA"),
      ("CT", "USA"),
      ("CT", "USA"),
      ("CT", "USA"),
      ("CT", "USA")).toDF("value", "country")
```

I was able to map it to an `RDD[((Int, String), Long)]`
colValCount: 
Read: ((colIdx, value), count)

```
((0,CT),5)
((0,MA),2)
((0,OH),4)
((0,NY),6)
((1,USA),17)
```

Now I need to get the top 2 items for each column index. So my expected output is this:

```
RDD[((Int, String), Long)]

((0,CT),5)
((0,NY),6)
((1,USA),17)
```

I've tried using freqItems api in DataFrame but it's slow.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think you need some combination of `sort()` and `limit()`, but TBH I don't understand how you get your output.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(lit(0).alias("index"), $"value")
   .union(df.select(lit(1), $"country"))
   .groupBy($"index", $"value")
   .count
  .orderBy($"count".desc)
  .limit(3)
  .show

// +-----+-----+-----+
// |index|value|count|
// +-----+-----+-----+
// |    1|  USA|   17|
// |    0|   NY|    6|
// |    0|   CT|    5|
// +-----+-----+-----+
```

where:

```
df.select(lit(0).alias("index"), $"value")
  .union(df.select(lit(1), $"country"))
```

creates a two column `DataFrame`:

```
// +-----+-----+
// |index|value|
// +-----+-----+
// |    0|   MA|
// |    0|   MA|
// |    0|   OH|
// |    0|   OH|
// |    0|   OH|
// |    0|   OH|
// |    0|   NY|
// |    0|   NY|
// |    0|   NY|
// |    0|   NY|
// |    0|   NY|
// |    0|   NY|
// |    0|   CT|
// |    0|   CT|
// |    0|   CT|
// |    0|   CT|
// |    0|   CT|
// |    1|  USA|
// |    1|  USA|
// |    1|  USA|
// +-----+-----+
```

If you want specifically two values for each column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def topN(df: DataFrame, key: String, n: Int)  = {
   df.select(
        lit(df.columns.indexOf(key)).alias("index"), 
        col(key).alias("value"))
     .groupBy("index", "value")
     .count
     .orderBy($"count")
     .limit(n)
}

topN(df, "value", 2).union(topN(df, "country", 2)).show
// +-----+-----+-----+ 
// |index|value|count|
// +-----+-----+-----+
// |    0|   MA|    2|
// |    0|   OH|    4|
// |    1|  USA|   17|
// +-----+-----+-----+
```

So like [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775083/top-n-items-from-a-spark-dataframe-rdd/48775323?noredirect=1#comment84551888_48775083) - just "*some combination of `sort()` and `limit()`*".

Comment: Some combination of `orderBy()` and `limit()`...basically what I said :-)

Comment: @pault Yeah, I guess it is either that or some combination of `groupBy` and `agg` here with a window function from time to time :-)

Comment: `.orderBy($"count".desc).limit(3)` gives the specified result in this case, but it doesn't give the top 2 items for each column index in the general case.

Comment: Thanks let me try it out!

Comment: @user8371915 this works but still slow for TB of data as I'm also running for 170+ columns. The performance is comparable to freqItems API I mentioned earlier. It takes around 1+ hour to process the entire data.

Comment: This process throws GC exception after a while: Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-39" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this - a natural window function - is by writing SQL. Spark comes with SQL syntax, and SQL is a great and expressive tool for this problem.

Register your dataframe as a temp table, and then group and window on it.

```
spark.sql("""SELECT idx, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idx ORDER BY c DESC) as r 
             FROM (
               SELECT idx, value, COUNT(*) as c 
               FROM (SELECT 0 as idx, value FROM df UNION ALL SELECT 1, country FROM df) 
               GROUP BY idx, value) 
             HAVING r <= 2""").show()
```

I'd like to see if any of the procedural / scala approaches will let you perform the window function without an iteration or loop. I'm not aware of anything in the Spark API that would support it.

Incidentally, if you have an arbitrary number of columns you want to include then you can quite easily generate the inner section (`SELECT 0 as idx, value ... UNION ALL SELECT 1, country`, etc) dynamically using the list of columns.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using window functions it complained of GC overhead. I'll try out your solution too.

Answer (score 2):

Given your last RDD:

```
val rdd =
  sc.parallelize(
    List(
      ((0, "CT"), 5),
      ((0, "MA"), 2),
      ((0, "OH"), 4),
      ((0, "NY"), 6),
      ((1, "USA"), 17)
    ))

rdd.filter(_._1._1 == 0).sortBy(-_._2).take(2).foreach(println)
> ((0,NY),6)
> ((0,CT),5)
rdd.filter(_._1._1 == 1).sortBy(-_._2).take(2).foreach(println)
> ((1,USA),17)
```

We first get items for a given column index (`.filter(_._1._1 == 0)`). Then we sort items by decreasing order (`.sortBy(-_._2)`). And finally, we take at most the 2 first elements (`.take(2)`), which takes only 1 element if the nbr of record is lower than 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can map each single partition using this helper function defined in Sparkz and then combine them together:

```
package sparkz.utils

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object TopElements {
  def topN[T: ClassTag](elems: Iterable[T])(scoreFunc: T => Double, n: Int): List[T] =
    elems.foldLeft((Set.empty[(T, Double)], Double.MaxValue)) {
      case (accumulator@(topElems, minScore), elem) =>
        val score = scoreFunc(elem)
        if (topElems.size < n)
          (topElems + (elem -> score), math.min(minScore, score))
        else if (score > minScore) {
          val newTopElems = topElems - topElems.minBy(_._2) + (elem -> score)
          (newTopElems, newTopElems.map(_._2).min)
        }
        else accumulator
    }
      ._1.toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse.map(_._1)
}
```

Source: https://github.com/gm-spacagna/sparkz/blob/master/src/main/scala/sparkz/utils/TopN.scala