# Top n items from specific column over date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I try to show the 5 tickers with the highest 'prct_chng' on a particular day for all days.
How prepare code which will do above task?

Sample data:

```
+------+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|TICKER|               DATE| OPEN| HIGH|  LOW|CLOSE|    VOL|  SMA50| SMA100|    prct_chng|
+------+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|   IAG|2020-07-22 00:00:00| 0.74| 0.74|0.685|0.725|  23873|  0.405|  0.308|        0.986|
|   ITM|2020-07-22 00:00:00|0.153|0.153|0.145| 0.15|   9230|  0.230|  0.290|        1.000|
|   ATG|2020-07-22 00:00:00| 4.96| 4.96| 4.91| 4.92|   1576|  4.552|  4.192|        1.002|
|   ALL|2020-07-22 00:00:00|  8.2| 8.66| 8.02|  8.4|  14009|  7.077|  6.684|        1.017|
|   SUW|2020-07-22 00:00:00| 17.0| 17.0| 16.8| 16.8|     35| 14.997| 13.481|        0.988|
|   SPH|2020-07-22 00:00:00| 14.0| 14.0| 14.0| 14.0|      8| 14.195| 15.620|        1.037|
|   CEZ|2020-07-22 00:00:00| 80.5| 80.5| 79.8| 79.9|    301| 78.593| 75.613|        0.988|
|   IMP|2020-07-22 00:00:00|  1.2| 1.27| 1.19| 1.27|  55998|  1.030|  0.945|        1.104|
|   4FM|2020-07-22 00:00:00| 4.82| 4.82| 4.57| 4.59|    255|  4.702|  4.397|        0.998|
|   ALR|2020-07-23 00:00:00|17.45| 17.6| 16.9|16.91| 327103| 17.006| 15.735|        0.971|
|   CCC|2020-07-23 00:00:00| 65.0| 65.1|62.94| 63.7| 156646| 63.383| 54.450|        0.986|
|   INK|2020-07-23 00:00:00|19.45|19.45|19.25|19.45|    861| 18.533| 16.939|        1.010|
|   WPL|2020-07-23 00:00:00| 75.6| 75.6| 71.6| 71.6|   3231| 70.950| 69.491|        0.957|
|   ECH|2020-07-23 00:00:00| 3.94| 3.98| 3.92| 3.95| 155636|  3.919|  3.984|        1.003|
|   TEN|2020-07-23 00:00:00|550.0|560.0|540.0|541.0|  17752|542.903|490.941|        0.975|
+------+-------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Answer for this question is really close to reply from this post [Top N items from a Spark DataFrame/RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775083/top-n-items-from-a-spark-dataframe-rdd)
however there is no division by date.

Comment: Please post your expected output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Window function -> row_number to partition by date and order by prct_chng in the desc order to select top5 ticker.

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window

    #InputDF
    # +------+-------------------+---------+
    # |TICKER|               DATE|prct_chng|
    # +------+-------------------+---------+
    # |   IAG|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    0.986|
    # |   ITM|2020-07-22 00:00:00|      1.0|
    # |   ATG|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.002|
    # |   ALL|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.017|
    # |   SUW|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    0.988|
    # |   SPH|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.037|
    # |   CEZ|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    0.988|
    # |   IMP|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.104|
    # |   4FM|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    0.998|
    # |   ALR|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.971|
    # |   CCC|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.986|
    # |   INK|2020-07-23 00:00:00|     1.01|
    # |   WPL|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.957|
    # |   ECH|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    1.003|
    # |   TEN|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.975|
    # +------+-------------------+---------+

    w= Window.partitionBy(F.to_timestamp("DATE")).orderBy(F.desc("prct_chng"))

    df.withColumn("r_no", F.row_number().over(w)).filter(F.col("r_no") <=5).drop("r_no").show()


    # +------+-------------------+---------+
    # |TICKER|               DATE|prct_chng|
    # +------+-------------------+---------+
    # |   IMP|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.104|
    # |   SPH|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.037|
    # |   ALL|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.017|
    # |   ATG|2020-07-22 00:00:00|    1.002|
    # |   ITM|2020-07-22 00:00:00|      1.0|
    # |   INK|2020-07-23 00:00:00|     1.01|
    # |   ECH|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    1.003|
    # |   CCC|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.986|
    # |   TEN|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.975|
    # |   ALR|2020-07-23 00:00:00|    0.971|
    # +------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: if there is a collision(having same value)  in prct_chng among tickers and you want to get all the tickers with same rank, you can use dense_rank().